# I want to know how can I access category name from Category name when working with Record table

Tags: android, sqlite, kotlin, mvvm

**//I want to access name of category in the adapter and viewModel while working with ExpRecord without having to add name in ExpRecord class**

```
@Entity(tableName = "Category")
data class ExpCategory(
   @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) val id: Int,
   @ColumnInfo(name = "category-name") val name: String )

@Entity(tableName = "Currency")
data class Currency(
   @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) val id: Int,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "symbol") val symbol: String )


@Entity(tableName = "Record",
  foreignKeys = [ ForeignKey(
    entity = ExpCategory::class,
    parentColumns = arrayOf("id"),
    childColumns = arrayOf("expCategoryID"),
    onDelete = ForeignKey.SET_NULL),

    ForeignKey(
        entity = Currency::class,
        parentColumns = arrayOf("id"),
        childColumns = arrayOf("currencyID"),
        onDelete = ForeignKey.SET_NULL)])
data class ExpRecord (
  @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) val recordNumber: Int,
  @ColumnInfo(name = "expCategoryID") val categoryId: Int,
  @ColumnInfo(name = "currencyID") val currencyId: Int,
  @ColumnInfo(name = "amount") val amount: Double,
  @ColumnInfo(name = "date") val date: String,
  @ColumnInfo(name = "notes") val note: String )
```

Answer (score 0):

Thats possible by querying multiple tables using Room DAOs. See [accessing multiple table data](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/accessing-data#multiple-tables)